# How to finds all object with the same value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database who is like this:

```
clubs: [
        {
          nomClub: "Nimes Olympique",
          classement: 01,
          dateMatch: new Date(2018, 8, 22),
          dateMatchStop: new Date("September 25, 2018"),
          classementDB: 01,
          logo: "/images/Monaco@2x.png",
          
          adversaire: "",
          tabDB: [],
          sommeDB: 0,
          pays: "France",
          ligue: "Ligue 1",
          moyenneRank: 100,
        },
        {
          nomClub: "FC Lorient",
          classement: 02,
          dateMatch: new Date("September 22, 2018"),
          dateMatchStop: new Date("September 25, 2018"),
          classementDB: 02,
          logo: "/images/Lorient@2x.png",
          
          adversaire: "",
          tabDB: [],
          sommeDB: 0,
          pays: "France",
          ligue: "Ligue 1",

          moyenneRank: 100,
        },{
          nomClub: "ASM Clermont Auvergne",
          classement: 20,
          dateMatch: new Date("September 22, 2018 "),
          dateMatchStop: new Date("September 25, 2018"),
          classementDB: 20,
          logo: "",
          adversaire: "",
          tabDB: [],
          sommeDB: 0,
          pays: "France",
          ligue: "Top 14",
          moyenneRank: 100,
        },
        {
          nomClub: "Aviron Bayonnais",
          classement: 20,
          dateMatch: new Date("September 22, 2018 "),
          dateMatchStop: new Date("September 25, 2018"),
          classementDB: 20,
          logo: "",
          adversaire: "",
          tabDB: [],
          sommeDB: 0,
          pays: "France",
          ligue: "Top 14",
          moyenneRank: 100,
        },
```

Now i want to render all the club who are in the "ligue": "Top 14" i tried with $elemmatch but only one results is render so for me the logical thing should be :

```
Sport.findOne(
      {"clubs.ligue": "Top 14"},
      

      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.json({ message: "une erreur s'est produite" });
        } else {
          res.json(data);
        }
      }
    );
```

I want to find in the "clubs.ligue" all the club who are in the top 14 but with this solution all the data is render even the club who are in the "ligue": "ligue 1"

I'm confused because the doc on mongoDB are saying the same so i don't know what am i missing

Comment: Try something like: `Sport.aggregate([{$match: { ligue: 'Top 14' } }])`

Comment: First thanks for you'r quick answer.

Second i did this : 

```
 Sport.aggregate([{$match: { "clubs.ligue": 'Top 14' } }]).exec((err,data)=>{
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({
          message: "pas ok ",
        });
      } else {
        res.json(data);
      }
    })
```

and it's render me all the tab like before

Comment: I see, so, you have an array and you're trying to access clubs.ligue, this is probably undefined, that could be why you're not getting the response you want.

Comment: Yeah but the filter are good i'm sure i don't see what else i can put except "clubs.ligue"

Comment: Is Club a collection or embedded inside documents in the Sport collection?

Comment: const ClubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nomClub: String,
  classement: Number,
  dateMatch: Date,
  dateMatchStop: Date,
  classementDB: Number,
  logo: String,
  adversaire: String,
  tabDB: [avgUser],
  sommeDB: Number,
  pays: String,
  ligue: String,
  moyenneRank: Number
    
  
});

const SportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  clubs: [ClubSchema],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("sport", SportSchema);

clubs is'nt the collection Sport is the collection and clubs is the array of all the object inside the sport collection

Comment: Did you try to use something like $elemmatch or $unwind? Searching for solutions with these two could help you I guess.

Comment: i tried an elematch but it is rendering only one answer not all the answer with the same filter

Comment: Okay, I just realized that you are using the findOne method, which will return only 1 resource as far as I know. Try changing to Sport.find(). Be aware that it will return the first 20 documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
//working code from Mongo Shell 4.2.6 CLI on Windows 10
> db.Sport.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f873edaf3b30cd04c8a78e4"),
        "clubs" : [
                {
                        "nomClub" : "Nimes Olympique",
                        "classement" : 1,
                        "dateMatch" : ISODate("2018-09-21T18:30:00Z"),
                        "dateMatchStop" : ISODate("2018-09-24T18:30:00Z"),
                        "classementDB" : 1,
                        "logo" : "/images/Monaco@2x.png",
                        "adversaire" : "",
                        "tabDB" : [ ],
                        "sommeDB" : 0,
                        "pays" : "France",
                        "ligue" : "Ligue 1",
                        "moyenneRank" : 100
                },
                {
                        "nomClub" : "FC Lorient",
                        "classement" : 2,
                        "dateMatch" : ISODate("2018-09-21T18:30:00Z"),
                        "dateMatchStop" : ISODate("2018-09-24T18:30:00Z"),
                        "classementDB" : 2,
                        "logo" : "/images/Lorient@2x.png",
                        "adversaire" : "",
                        "tabDB" : [ ],
                        "sommeDB" : 0,
                        "pays" : "France",
                        "ligue" : "Ligue 1",
                        "moyenneRank" : 100
                },
                {
                        "nomClub" : "ASM Clermont Auvergne",
                        "classement" : 20,
                        "dateMatch" : ISODate("2018-09-21T18:30:00Z"),
                        "dateMatchStop" : ISODate("2018-09-24T18:30:00Z"),
                        "classementDB" : 20,
                        "logo" : "",
                        "adversaire" : "",
                        "tabDB" : [ ],
                        "sommeDB" : 0,
                        "pays" : "France",
                        "ligue" : "Top 14",
                        "moyenneRank" : 100
                },
                {
                        "nomClub" : "Aviron Bayonnais",
                        "classement" : 20,
                        "dateMatch" : ISODate("2018-09-21T18:30:00Z"),
                        "dateMatchStop" : ISODate("2018-09-24T18:30:00Z"),
                        "classementDB" : 20,
                        "logo" : "",
                        "adversaire" : "",
                        "tabDB" : [ ],
                        "sommeDB" : 0,
                        "pays" : "France",
                        "ligue" : "Top 14",
                        "moyenneRank" : 100
                }
        ]
}
> db.Sport.aggregate([
... {$unwind: "$clubs"},
... {$match:{"clubs.ligue":"Top 14"}}
... ]).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f873edaf3b30cd04c8a78e4"),
        "clubs" : {
                "nomClub" : "ASM Clermont Auvergne",
                "classement" : 20,
                "dateMatch" : ISODate("2018-09-21T18:30:00Z"),
                "dateMatchStop" : ISODate("2018-09-24T18:30:00Z"),
                "classementDB" : 20,
                "logo" : "",
                "adversaire" : "",
                "tabDB" : [ ],
                "sommeDB" : 0,
                "pays" : "France",
                "ligue" : "Top 14",
                "moyenneRank" : 100
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f873edaf3b30cd04c8a78e4"),
        "clubs" : {
                "nomClub" : "Aviron Bayonnais",
                "classement" : 20,
                "dateMatch" : ISODate("2018-09-21T18:30:00Z"),
                "dateMatchStop" : ISODate("2018-09-24T18:30:00Z"),
                "classementDB" : 20,
                "logo" : "",
                "adversaire" : "",
                "tabDB" : [ ],
                "sommeDB" : 0,
                "pays" : "France",
                "ligue" : "Top 14",
                "moyenneRank" : 100
        }
}
> print("MongoDB",db.version());
MongoDB 4.2.6
>
```